# How to add int numbers to json data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a small script that create JSON. I want to add field **track_ID** and this field wll be int. Idea is to add some loop in which it starts from 1 and finish when objects gone.
Any ideas?

```
 for list in obj['frames']['objects']:
                        data = {
                            'track_ID': 
                            'object_id': obj['info']['doc']
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `i` in it, something like this

```py
i = 0
for list in obj['frames']['objects']:
                        data = {
                            'track_ID': i
                            'object_id': obj['info']['doc']
                        }
                        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/amp/)() will do that beautifully

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`.
Note that your loop overrides the value of `data` in every iteration, `list` is a saved word in python and you don't actually use the value of `list` in your code example.

```
for idx, list in enumerate(obj['frames']['objects']):
     data = {
        'track_ID': idx+1 
         'object_id': obj['info']['doc']
     }
```